# Change Language without leaving current page

Tags: php

I am trying to change languages but stay on the current page:
i.e:

www.myurl.com/english/aboutus.php

www.myurl.com/german/aboutus.php

www.myurl.com/french/aboutus.php

So only the language directory changes.
I have the following but can't get it to work:

```
<?php 
$full_url = $_SERVER['FULL_URL'] ;  

$temparray = explode(".com/",$full_url,2); 

$englishtemp = $temparray[0] . ".com/english/" . $temparray[1]; 
$englishlink = "<a href=$englishtemp><img src=../images/english-flag.jpg></a>"; 

echo $englishlink; 
?>
```

I get the url to change from '/french/aboutus.php' to '/english' but it doesn't remember the page name 'aboutus.php' and returns to the index page.

Could any one please help?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into ajax? Even so, perhaps you are better off refreshing the page anyhow. What's wrong with that?

Comment: edited the Q. to make it a little clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` for the current page.

```
$englishtemp = "/english/" . basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
$englishlink = "<a href=$englishtemp><img src=../images/english-flag.jpg></a>";
echo $englishlink;
```

See [PHP documentation on $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: Thanks Antony, it works! - just had to remove the '$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .' bit from the first link because it was duplicating the URL - thanks again!

Comment: @dave Edited answer to remove `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. It will generate links for all the languages except the current selected one :)

```
<?php
$full_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //select full url without the domain name
$languages = array('english', 'french', 'german'); //array of all supported languages

$url_bits = explode('/', $full_url); //divide url into bits by /
$current_language = $url_bits[1]; //current language is held in the second item of the array

//find current language in the array and remove it so we wouldn't have to display it
unset($languages[array_search($current_language, $languages)]);

$links = '';

foreach ($languages as $language) {
    //generate links with images for the rest of the languages
    $links .= '<a href="/' . $language . '/' . $url_bits[2] . '"><img src="../images/' . $language . '-flag.jpg" title="'.ucfirst($language).'" /></a>';
}

echo $links;
?>
```

Comment: In my personal opinion, I don't like using URLs with the domain name, better to just use absolute paths (url starting with a /), but it's up to you :) Looks cleaner :)

Comment: Thanks Ignas - Appreciate you taking your time to do this, Antonys solution worked for me on this occasion but yours looks good too! Thanks again!